# Screen scrape php output

Tags: php, curl, screen-scraping, simple-html-dom

For testing purposes Im trying to scrape bbc. There is a "weather widget" if you scroll down: http://www.bbc.co.uk/

If you type a city to search for a call is made that looks like this:

```
http://www.bbc.co.uk/wwhp?module=weather&action=search&location_term=amsterdam
```

After you click on list of available city's you will get the data from this call:

```
http://www.bbc.co.uk/wwhp?module=weather&action=set&location_id=2759794
```

When I scrape the entire website and fill in the weather widget I get a error in console:

```
OPTIONS http://www.bbc.co.uk/wwhp?module=weather&action=search&location_term=amsterdam Origin http://mydomain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. jquery-1.4.js:23
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.bbc.co.uk/wwhp?module=weather&action=search&location_term=amsterdam. Origin http://mydomain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. myproxy.php:1
```

When I scrape the generated urls (the first two from above) I get a blank screen. Im scraping with CURL and simple html dom. Why cant I scrape the above urls? What can I try?

Comment: the link gives me a json output

Comment: I just realized Im parsing as HTML...That could be the problem...Can someone please tell me what the code language of the urls is and how to parse them with simple html dom or curl...?

Comment: @DevZer0 Thanks, so I have to parse as JSON..?

Comment: yes use `json_decode`